# How to Login into Gmail using OAuth in Android Application?

Tags: android, gmail, oauth-2.0

I am Developing an application which uses Login to Gmail.I gone through all tutorials,stackoverflow questions which is tagged under `OAuth 2.0` and documents that are available in google and finally as per the guide lines given in official document of Google for `OAuth 2.0`  [sample](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode). I have created Client ID and everything that is required for installed applications i.e., for Android. Everything up to now works fine,and i called `WebView` to grant permission from the user,After that i got `Accesstoken` like  `4/cR7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` in the `WebView`and saying something like `Please copy this code,switch to your application and paste it here`.I am confused here,i don't know what to do,to get back to my app from `Webview` .Am searching for the solution about two days but,Am not able to get good answer for my problem.Here is the code where i was got stoped.

`Main.java` where user have an `OptionMenu` to login. When the user clicks `WebView`opens to enter gmail.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {
    public static String REQUEST = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
            + "client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX-gxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&"
            + "redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&"
            + "scope=https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom&"
            + "response_type=code&" + "access_type=online";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (requestCode != RESULT_OK || data == null) {
                return;
            }
            String token = data.getStringExtra("token");
            if (token != null) {

            }
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            Intent intent_obj2 = new Intent(Main.this, Webview.class);
            intent_obj2.setData(Uri.parse(REQUEST));
            startActivityForResult(intent_obj2, 0);
            return true;
            }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Webview.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Webview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        final WebView wb_obj = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(wb_obj);
        wb_obj.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getData() != null) {
            wb_obj.loadUrl(intent.getDataString());
        }

        wb_obj.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                setProgress(newProgress * 10000);
            }

        });
        wb_obj.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                setTitle(url);
                System.out.println(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                System.out.println("in onPageFinsihed");

                /*CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                String s_cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                if (s_cookie == null) {
                    System.out.println(s_cookie);
                    return;
                }else{

                String web_title = wb_obj.getTitle().toString();
                System.out.println("web tile" + web_title);

                if (web_title.equalsIgnoreCase("Request for Permission")) {

                } else {

                    String[] s_webtitle = web_title.split("=", 2);
                    String access_token = s_webtitle[1].toString();
                    //System.out.println("Access token" + access_token);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Webview.this, Main.class));
                    finish();
                }*/
                }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(Webview.this, Main.class));
    }
}
```

As per Webview.java i called `finish()` so that current activity gets killed but this is nit happening in this app,so that i will get token in `onAcitivityResult()`.Please share Your answers thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below steps are require to login to Google.

**1-** Select an account from your device using below code

```
public static AccountManager accountManager;
accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

**2-** Get a Token from selected account using below code

```
private void onAccountSelected(final Account account) {
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
    try {
        String token = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        useToken(account, token);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
        onAccessDenied();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
    }
}
}, null);

}
```

**3-** now Authenticate the Token using user account and Token. you will be able to login to google.

***NOTE:*** you will get Authentication full code from here [Authentication code](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode) , put your gmail a/c and token where required. now you are able to loging using OAuth.

**4-**  for re login you have to invalidate your token using below code

```
accountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", token);
```

**5-** after invalidate you have to get a new token using below code

```
 String newToken = AccountManager.get(this).getAuthToken(new Account(account,        "com.google"),
             AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, null, null).getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

**6-** in your AndroidManifest.xml add below uses permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

Thats all you require, now enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But i Don't want to use `AccountManager`. Beacause app may have many number of user from a mobile..

Comment: @IPL - I got the token but I am not able use this token to retrieve email.. can you gist out how to use the token to retrieve emails from my gmail inbox?

Comment: you will get full code from here http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode

Comment: I have also edited above code follow that, i am sure you'll succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using "localhost:port" as the redirect uri instead of urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob& (for more details refer to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#installed-apps) and trap this URL being loaded in the webview in the callback:
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url).

Answer (score -1):

For an alternative way of accessing the Gmail API with an OAuth2 token, you may consider the answers from this post: [OAuth and Java (connecting to GMail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049462/oauth-and-java-connecting-to-gmail/27632895#27632895).